# How to apply scaling to all keyframes?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm currently retargeting an animated rig to another rig. I'm having a problem scaling the animated rig to the size of the other. The rescaling only applies to the 0th keyframe. Does anyone know how to fix this? Also, is there another more effective and easier way of doing this? Thanks!

**0th frame with the correct rescaling**
[image]

---

**other unaffected frame that did not change the original scale**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With graph editor

Open graph editor:

[image]

Hide everything except scale using eye icons:

[image]

Move all points up to scale the object:

[image]

### Alternative way

If the scale is not animated, you can do this easier.

In the frame with correct scaling, click RMB on scale values, to see context menu:

[image]

Click on **clear keyframes**. Now the scale is not animated, you can set any.